# mozilla link does not get updated

Tags: html, coldfusion, mozilla

I am unable to see the updated CF fiel on mozilla ,  where as it works fine on Windows.

Working on a coldfuison 'MX.

In the folder kings.com/ ,the page "testGuide.cfm" exists.In it the values have been defined as

```
<cfset TestGuide    = "#appDirMisc#testGuide.html">
<cfset TestexZip = "#appDirMisc#TestGuide.zip">
<cfset TestGuideEx = "#appDirMisc#zippedTestGuide.exe">
```

and the page is written as 
" You can view the guide

```
 You can view the guide
        `<a href="#TestGuide    #" target="_blank">`online`</a>`,
```

in a
            separate browser window "

There is "misc" folder kings.com/misc ...containing all testGuide.html ,TestGuide.zip and 
zippedTestGuide.exe.
when i update the #appDirMisc# , assuming that it is kings.com/misc, by copy pasting the latest testGuide.html ,TestGuide.zip and  zippedTestGuide.exe.

I always open the OLD TestGuide    in MOZILLA but IT WORKS WELL IN WINDOWS where it opens as a tab

Kindly help me in openeingf the right file in Mozilla.

Comment: what's "IN MOZILLA"? you mean FireFox?
"WORKS WELL IN WINDOWS"? you mean IE?
Did you clear your browser cache? check View -> Page Source

Comment: Your question is a bit messed and not very understandable, but... It can be something with caching in the Firefox. Does Ctrl-R help? If yes, try to check the client caching settings on your web-server.

Answer (score 1):

If it does end up being a caching issue, add a random string to the link and see if that solves it.

```
<cfset noCache = DateFormat(Now(), "ddmmyyyy") & TimeFormat(Now(), "HHmmss")>

<a href="link-here.cfm?noCache=#noCache#">Click me</a>
```